# Rule to save attachments to file with today's date

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

I save an attachment, that I get sent daily, to a folder on my network.

I want to prefix the document with the date on which it was saved.

The attachment is named summary.rtf.
I'd like it to be 20160805_summary.rtf etc.

My code:

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "X:\Tessitura\Shared Full Access\Secure_CXL_Reports"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the below section into the line, format will change the form of your date to the one required and date will return the current date, change the y/d/m for the format as required.

```
format(date, "yyyymmdd")
```

This is the line inserted into your code.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "X:\Tessitura\Shared Full Access\Secure_CXL_Reports"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & format(date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that worked!! Thank you so much, it's been boggling my brain for too long!